# Excluir arquivo.php, juntamente com exclusão de registro no banco de dados, obtendo o nome do arquivo.php por uma variável

Tags: php

Olá, pessoal! Possuo um cadastro com id, titulo, data e evento, no banco de dados, de modo que, ao se fazer um novo cadastro, a pessoa preenche somente o titulo e a data, e o campo "evento" é automaticamente preenchido com o "titulo" que a pessoa escreveu, acrescido de ".php".

Então é criada uma página nova com o mesmo nome do título e a extensão .php, que é acessada em um calendário, de modo que a data cadastrada se torna um link para tal página nova criada.

Então eu criei uma listagem dos dados do banco, com um botão de excluir. Contudo, não consigo, ao apertar este mesmo botão, excluir junto o arquivo.php referente àquele id que será excluído do banco.

o registro é listado em admin.php, onde há o botão de excluir:

```
<!--EXCLUIR EVENTO-->
<?php

$resgatando_dados = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM eventos ORDER BY data ASC");
$resgatando_dados->execute();
echo '
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr id="cabecalhotabelalistar";>
<td>Id</td>
<td>Título</td>
<td>Data</td>
<td>Encontro</td>
<td>Excluir</td>
</tr>
';

foreach($resgatando_dados as $apresenta_dados):
echo ' 
<tr>
<td> '.addslashes(trim(strip_tags($apresenta_dados['id']))).'</td>
<td> '.addslashes(trim(strip_tags($apresenta_dados['titulo']))).'</td>
<td> '.addslashes(trim(strip_tags($apresenta_dados['data']))).'</td>
<td> '.addslashes(trim(strip_tags($apresenta_dados['encontro']))).'</td>
<td><a href="deletar_dados.php?id='.addslashes(trim(strip_tags($apresenta_dados['id']))).'">Excluir</a></td>
</tr>
';
endforeach;
echo '</table>';

?>
```

E o arquivo php "deletar_dados" é este:

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<?php

$id = strip_tags($_GET['id']);



$encontro = $_GET['encontro'];
unlink ('encontros/'.'$encontro');



$deletando_dados = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM eventos WHERE id = '$id'");
$deletando_dados->execute();



if($deletando_dados):
echo '<script>alert("Evento excluído")</script>';
//echo '<script>window.location="admin.php"</script>';

else:
echo '<script>alert("Não foi possível excluir o evento")</script>';
endif;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

*obs: o arquivo a ser excluído está em uma pasta dentro da pasta onde estão os arquivos aqui exibidos (  daí o unlink ('encontros/'.'$encontro');  ).

Considerando que se trata de um problema que articula várias dúvidas frequentes, somando arquivos excluídos em outra pasta, com exclusão automática juntamente com os dados do banco, e ainda cujo nome se obtém por meio de uma variável, penso que a solução será de utilidade para muita gente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável `$_GET['encontro']` é do tipo `null`, por isso não está encontrando o arquivo e deletando-o.

É necessário que você adicione-a como parâmetro da URL.

```
<td><a href="deletar_dados.php?id='.urlencode($apresenta_dados['id']).'&encontro='.urlencode($apresenta_dados['encontro']).'">Excluir</a></td>
```

Porém, o ideal é faze algumas validações antes: verificar se tem permissão para fazer isso; buscar o nome do arquivo no banco de dados ao invés de passa-lo como parâmetro etc.

Quando você pasa essa informação sem validar, dar margens para uma pessoa remover **qualquer** arquivo do seu servidor.

Comment: Opa! Já melhorou! Obrigado, Valdeir! 

Mas outra coisa está errada no meu código que eu não havia percebido... 

Agora surge a seguinte mensagem: 

"Warning: unlink(encontros/$encontro): No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\administrador\calendario\deletar_dados.php on line 19"

Quando eu coloco diretamente o nome da página.php a ser excluída, eu consigo... a exclusão acontece com o arquivo que está dentro da pasta "encontros", que é uma pasta dentro da pasta onde estão os demais arquivos. Mas quando faço a exclusão por meio da variável, então esse erro surge. alguma sugestão aí?

Comment: @A.Goes é porque você está passando a variável entre aspas simples. O correto é `unlink ('encontros/'.$encontro);`

Comment: Pois é! Eu tava olhando isso exatamente agora... perdão pela gafe. E muito obrigado pela rapidez na ajuda!